# Android - perform repititve task in service

Tags: android

I'd like to add a repititive taksk to a Service in my Android app. I've read about Runnable/Handler constructs, and about the Timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(). I'm wondering which one is the best approach.

I'm especially worried about the "scheduleAtFixedRate()" being run multiple times at once if execution takes longer than the interval. Or is that not possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static final long DELAY = 4000;

TimerTask task= new TimerTask (){
    public void run(){
        //do what you needs.
        timer.shedule(this, DELAY);
    }
}



Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.shedule(task, 0);
```

You can try this.

Answer (score 1):

How long is the interval? For this purpose, i think is good to use android [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

It is for scheduling events on android, you can see a nice example [here](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html). And you can choose the method **setRepeating** instead **set** for repetive events.

Comment: teepee: the interval is something like "2 minutes" ... it's a repititive task. I'd like to check a certain url every X minutes (2, 5, maybe 10, ...) for new content.